# The best way to run multiple Powershell commands?

Tags: c#, powershell

For example, if we run this command:

```
Get-VM
```

and if we have a lot of VMs, we need to wait a few seconds to get the VM and all their information.

So for optimization, we can, for example, do this:

```
Get-VM | Select Name, Id
```

And get VMs with only their Name and Id.

But how is this best done on C#?
I don't sure that code will work, it just example of idea.
I took the idea from here - [Run multiple powershell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378696/run-multiple-powershell-commands)

First example of "Get-VM | Select Name, Id":

```
List<Command> commandList = new List<Command>();

Command cmd = new Command("Get-VM");
cmd.Parameters.Add("par", str); //add some parameters -par "name"
commandList.Add(cmd);

Command cmd2 = new Command("Select Id, Name");
commandList.Add(cmd2);

Pipeline pipeline;
Collection<PSObject> Results = null;

foreach (Command command in commandList)
{   
    pipeline = runspacee.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
    Results = pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

Yes, I know that I can send it like a script - `Command("Get-VM | Select Id, Name", true);`

Second example of "Get-VM | Select Name, Id":

```
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

ps.Runspace = rs;
ps.AddCommand("Get-VM").AddParameter("par", str); //add some parameters -par "name"
ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Select").AddArgument("Id, Name");
ps.Invoke();
```

If I understand correctly, my first example would be to execute the command twice? First `Get-VM` and then `Select Name, Id`
And my second example at one time will run `Get-VM | Select Name, Id`?

In the end, the best option is the second? Or is there no difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: `Get-VM | Select Name, Id` is not an optimization, it's slower. You still have to wait to get all the details, but then you need to process them all and throw some of the details away, and make new objects and copy the Name and Id into them so you can keep them. It's more work.

Comment: Really? But on Windows 2012R2 I get VMs 3 times faster with Select.

Comment: Or does the Powershell cache work there?

Comment: :O   Is this Hyper-V rather than VMware (both have a `Get-VM`)?  I'm surprised; if you `measure-command { get-vm }` and `measure-command {get-vm | select name, id }` are they also showing that it's faster with 'select'? Could it be the output formatting and screen display of all the data which takes longer?

Comment: I made the test again, With "select" I get information after 7 seconds, without "select" after 56 seconds.

Comment: That really shouldn't be the case because you're setting up a pipeline, tearing it down, and processing *every* object..  Use `Measure-Command` and validate your findings.

Comment: Oh, I see, i think I found a mistake :) Anyway the difference is only 40 milliseconds

Comment: In any case, there is no way how I can get only the information I need without Select?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Without "Select" Yes it is a little bit faster, but when I work with this data, I will spend much more time if I immediately get from "Select".

Comment: However, if I correctly understood the previous comments above, in this case 2 codes in C#, are about the same as the runtime or not?